# Port Forwarding does not work. Ports are open but my IP does not connect through any ports to anyone

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, ftp, port-forwarding, port

Recently I just a got a new got a new CenturyLink/**Zyxel** router. Since then I haven't been able to successfully reach my IP through any kind of port. I have been wanting to access and FTP file server the report 21 (default FTP port) but it wont connect. I've been trying to do the same with a Minecraft server through the port 25565, but this does not work as well I have been having troubles since this new router. It is helpful to know that it is a router that has two networks a 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. I have done a lot of troubleshooting in my router's configuration on the line. I have tried messing with my firewall disabling in enabling NAT. I have allowed everything I can to not get blocked through my firewall and have tried this both on A Windows Lenovo computer and Mac computer.

I have noticed this can be a common problem with some people. I have no doubt that this is my ISP's fault if you can figure out what's I could do to troubleshoot this anymore that would be greatly appreciated. I am going to call customer support in a day or two. If you have any experience with Internet services I would love to hear your take on this.

Comment: Can you post the first two octets of the IP address assigned to the routers wan interface?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from an external network or [from within your own network](https://superuser.com/questions/1253582/unable-to-reach-self-domain-name-from-inside-lan-network/1253586)?

Comment: Your title says port forwarding doesn't work but you didn't mention it in your question. Did you forward the ports? Keep in mind NAT isn't port forwarding. Also, different WiFi GHz doesn't equal different networks.  If it worked fine with your old router and not your new one then it's a configuration issue and not ISP (unless they just happen to start blocking them which I doubt).

Answer (score 1):

CenturyLink doesn't make routers. Please respond back with the actual manufacturer.

The most likely scenario, is your Windows or Mac computer is blocking the port or your firewall(router) is not configured correctly. Ports must be "forwarded" through the firewall. That means there must be a rule allowing traffic on the incoming port and the NAT directs the traffic to the device on your local network. In consumer grade router/firewalls, it is often just a port forwarding or "virtual server" page that does both at the same time.

Comment: They do infact send out routers that are "CenturyLink" custom. I.e they have a CenturyLink custom firmware installed on them. The op seems to understand port forwarding.

Comment: My IP is static and is 174.20.140.xxx